# Add the following instance methods to the Person class

Tags: java

buyPass(TicketBoothbooth) ­ This method simulates the person buying a ride pass from the given booth object. It should modify the person and the booth in the appropriate way, and then return a boolean indicating whether or not the transaction was successful. The transaction is successful ONLY if the booth has a pass available AND the person has enough money for the pass.

This is what I have so far under the person class.

```
public class Person{

float height;
float money;
int ticketCount;
boolean hasPass;

public Person(){

height = 0.0f;
money = 0.0f;
ticketCount = 0;
hasPass = false;
}

public Person(float h, float m) {

height = h;
money = m;
ticketCount = 0;
hasPass = false;

}
public String toString(){

if(hasPass)
{
return(this.height + "' person with $" + this.money + " and has a pass");
}
else
{
  return(this.height + "' person with $" + this.money + " and " + this.ticketCount + " tickets");
}
}
public void useTickets(int numberOfTickets){

if(this.ticketCount >= numberOfTickets)
{
  this.ticketCount -= numberOfTickets;
}
}

public int buyPass(TicketBooth booth){

if (boolean availablePasses || money < 16.50){

  boolean message_3 = false; 
  return message_3;

}
}

}
```

and this is what i have under the TicketBooth class

```
public class TicketBooth
{

 float moneyMade;
 int availablePasses;
 int availableTickets;

static final double TICKET_PRICE = 0.50;
static final double PASS_PRICE = 16.50;

public TicketBooth() 
  {
    moneyMade = 0.0f;
    availablePasses = 0;
    availableTickets = 0;
  }

  public TicketBooth(int passes)
  {
    moneyMade = 0.0f;
    availablePasses = passes;
    availableTickets = 0;
  }

  public TicketBooth(int passes, int tickets) 
  {
    moneyMade = 0.0f;
    availablePasses = passes;
    availableTickets = tickets;
  }
  public String toString(){

  String message_2;

  message_2 = "Ticket booth with " + availablePasses + 
    " passes and " + availableTickets + " tickets";

return message_2;
}

public boolean sellPass() {

 if (availablePasses > 0) {
   moneyMade = moneyMade + 16.50f;
   availablePasses--; 
   return true;
 }
 else{
 return false;
 }
 }

public boolean sellTickets(int ticketsWanted) {
if(availableTickets >= ticketsWanted) {
    moneyMade += ticketsWanted * 0.50;
    availableTickets -= ticketsWanted;
           return true;
}
else{
return false;
}

}



}
```

however, i keep getting these errors.

```
File: /Users/joshbourbonniere/Documents/COMP 1006/Assignment 2/Person.java  [line: 45]
Error: '.class' expected
File: /Users/joshbourbonniere/Documents/COMP 1006/Assignment 2/Person.java  [line: 45]
Error: illegal start of expression
File: /Users/joshbourbonniere/Documents/COMP 1006/Assignment 2/Person.java  [line: 45]
Error: ';' expected
File: /Users/joshbourbonniere/Documents/COMP 1006/Assignment 2/Person.java  [line: 45]
Error: illegal start of type
File: /Users/joshbourbonniere/Documents/COMP 1006/Assignment 2/Person.java  [line: 45]
Error: illegal start of expression
File: /Users/joshbourbonniere/Documents/COMP 1006/Assignment 2/Person.java  [line: 45]
Error: ';' expected
File: /Users/joshbourbonniere/Documents/COMP 1006/Assignment 2/Person.java  [line: 53]
Error: class, interface, or enum expected
```

Any help or recommendations would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you think this `if (boolean availablePasses || money < 16.50){` does? Use an IDE or learn the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

`if ( boolean availablePasses||money< 16.50){` is invalid syntax.  You can't declare a variable inside of an `if` statement.

You need to extract the properties from the `TicketBooth` before you can use them here.

```
if(ticketBooth.getAvailablePasses() > 0 && money < 16.50) { // Other logic ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int buyPass(TicketBooth booth){ ...
```

should retun an `int` but you declare and return an `boolean`

```
if (boolean availablePasses || money < 16.50){

  boolean message_3 = false; 
  return message_3;

}
```

Also the variable `message_3` should be declared outside the `if` statement.

Try (if you want a boolean):

```
public boolean buyPass(TicketBooth booth)
{
boolean message_3 = false;
    if (boolean availablePasses || money < 16.50)
    { 
      return message_3;
    }
// do something else
}
```